# How can I read content form a local file with flutter for web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to make a Flutter Web App like Blog System,but when I use the library 'dart:io', I found it doesn't supported in Flutter for Web.
So,how can I read content from a local markdown file with Flutter for web? Thx!
And apology for My poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see an example here on the flutter web samples repo.

https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/master/web/github_dataviz/lib/main.dart
Check the  `Future loadGitHubData() async` function.

They have used HttpRequest.getString() method. This is ideally a client side request as per the docs here.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-html/HttpRequest-class.html

I am not sure if this is what you want. If you want to just access the contents of the MD file this should help. But if you want to process it into an html or something you probably have to do it in your server.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I needed to read a .svg file as text. This was my solution:

```
import 'dart:html';


readFile(String path) async {
    var request = await HttpRequest.request(path);
    var response = request.response;

    return response;
}
```

**Note:**

Path used: "assets/someImage.svg"

Returns: File contents as a String

I included this note for context.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to read a local mock binary file for the web. This solution works for me:

1. Add a file to assets:

```
root_folder/assets/mock/awesome_file.bin
```

2. Update pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/mock/
```

3. Get data:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<List<int>?> getBinaryFile() async {
  try {
    final ByteData file = await rootBundle.load('assets/mock/awesome_file.bin');
    final List<int> bytes = file.buffer.asUint8List(file.offsetInBytes, file.lengthInBytes);
    return bytes;
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print('Error getting the binary file: $e');
    return null;
  }
}
```